# Answered - CS50 PSet4 Recover: Getting Segmention fault (core dumped)

Tags: cs50, recover

I am getting a 'Segmentation fault (core dumped) error'

I know that means I am accessing memory I shouldn't.

The error is coming in the outer else loop with the fwrite function. fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover IMAGE\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("File entered does not exist\n");
        return 1;
    }

    typedef uint8_t BYTE;
    BYTE buffer[512];
    char filename[8];
    int i = 0;
    FILE *img;
    while (fread(buffer, 1, 512, file) == 512)
    {
        // check if first three bytes are 0xff 0xd8 0xff
        // check if 4th byte is 0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, ..., 0xef
        // if those 4 bytes are found then start writing these bytes to a file ###.jpg
        // once you see the 4 bytes again, stop writing to the current file and make a new file ###.jpg to write to
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", i);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                i += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                fclose(img);
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", i);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                i += 1;
            }
            fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img);
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img);
        }
    }
    fclose(img);

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas, hints or tips would be appreciated.
This is my first time posting in stackoverflow :D

Solved:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover IMAGE\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("File entered does not exist\n");
        return 1;
    }

    typedef uint8_t BYTE;
    BYTE buffer[512];
    char filename[8];
    int i = 0;
    FILE *img;
    while (fread(buffer, 1, 512, file) == 512)
    {
        // check if first three bytes are 0xff 0xd8 0xff
        // check if 4th byte is 0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, ..., 0xef
        // if those 4 bytes are found then start writing these bytes to a file ###.jpg
        // once you see the 4 bytes again, stop writing to the current file and make a new file ###.jpg to write to
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", i);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                i += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                fclose(img);
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", i);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                i += 1;
            }
            fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img);
        }
        else
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(img);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: if `argc == 2`, then `argv[1]` cannot be `== NULL`.

Comment: I would roughly guess that you need `filename[8]` to be at least slightly larger (depending on the possible values of `i`).

Comment: Also, I suggest you spend some minimal effort to debug your code. For one, you could find the line where the error occurs, and share your findings with the readers. Moreover, at that point, you could also investigate the error a little further before posting it. For example, if the error occurs at `fopen(filename, "w")`, then you can verify that `filename` contains the name of a valid file.

Comment: P.S.: note that you're not closing any of these files, so you could easily get an error by attempting to open an already opened file. You definitely need to execute `fclose(img)` inside the loop, and not outside of it.

Comment: I switched agv[1] == NULL to file == NULL and declared file earlier. The problem said there is only 50 jpg so I think filename[8] is ok. Thanks for the feedback, I will use the debugger and go through line by line.

Comment: I have removed the fopen in the outer else loop so that it isn't opening a file thats already open. And when I run debugger it gives the error at the fwrite function in the outer else loop.

Comment: I think it's because before I open img I am already writing to it. So I need to open a file outside the loops.